# Search filter is not updating in collection view.When i type a value A its Assets showing after another value is typed in search

Tags: swift4, swift4.1

//When i click a letter for example A ,its data is coming from server but not filling in collection view.When i click letter S ,A value assets are filling in collection view.AS value is showing when ever i remove A from AS value. //

@objc var filteredDataItems = Array()

```
@objc var searchCollectionList1 = NSMutableArray()


func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)

   {

    searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white

   let lists:Array = searchCollectionList1 as Array

       searchFilter(searchName: searchText)

       filteredDataItems = lists

       print(searchText)

       self.collectionView.reloadData()

   }



func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController)

   {

      searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

   }



@objc func searchFilter(searchName:String)

   {

       self.searchCollectionList1.removeAllObjects()

       let url = KsearchFilter + “appname=\(kAppName)”

       if self.debugPrint == true

       {

           print(“searchFilter--URL--SearchListViewController-----\(url)-------------“)

       }

       let parameters = [“search”:searchName]



       ApiManager.sharedManager.postDataWithJsonLambda(url: url, parameters: parameters)

       {

           (responseDict,error,isDone)in

          // print(“responseDictresponseDict\(String(describing: responseDict))“)

           if self.debugPrint == true

           {

               print(“searchFilter--Response--SearchListViewController-----\(String(describing: responseDict))-------------“)

           }

           if error == nil

           {

               let json = responseDict as! NSDictionary

               if json[“statusCode”] != nil

               {

                   let status = json[“statusCode”] as! Int

                   if status == 200

                   {

                       //self.updateSearchResults(for: UISearchController)

                       let result = json[“result”] as! NSArray

                       print(“Search result\(result.count)“)

                       self.searchCollectionList1.addObjects(from: result as! [Any])

                       print(“searchCollectionList1\(self.searchCollectionList1)“)

                   }

                   else

                   {

                       print(“json error status code not 200 getaccountInfo SearchListViewController”)

                   }

               }

               else

               {

                   print(“json error getaccountInfo SearchListViewController”)

               }

           }

           else

           {

               print(error?.localizedDescription ?? “getaccountInfo got with error”)

           }

       }

   }
```

- When i click a letter for example A ,its data is coming from server
  but not filling in collection view.
- When i click letter S ,A value
  assets are filling in collection view.AS value is showing when ever i
  remove A from AS value.

Comment: When i click a letter for example A ,its data is coming from server but not filling in collection view.When i click letter S ,A value assets are filling in collection view.AS value is showing when ever i remove A from AS value.

Comment: include your comment in question. @Satish Kumar

Answer (score 0):

You should put your reload related code in async block.

```
if status == 200
{           
    let result = json[“result”] as! NSArray

    print(“Search result\(result.count)“)

    self.searchCollectionList1.addObjects(from: result as! [Any])

    print(“searchCollectionList1\(self.searchCollectionList1)“)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Now, you can comment this line in the following function

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)

    // YOUR EXISTING CODE HERE
    // Comment the line to reload the collectionView, as we have already doing this in block.
    //self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Try and share the results you are getting!

Comment: i tried but problem is not solved.is there any other solution to solve this?

Comment: Please record and add a video, explaining the exact issue you are seeing.

Comment: also try looking at this tutorial to https://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/ to get the idea, if you are missing something in that.